# Entity framework Code first returns detached objects when called using IRepository pattern

Tags: entity-framework, irepository

Trying to fetch an object using IRepository pattern with Entity Framework Code First. Usually when calling the repository, it will return an object which is attached to the context, and changes will be traced. My problem now is that the repository seems to only return detached objects.

When adding one object to another, my savechange will treat both the objects connected to eachother as inserted instead of inserting one and connect the other as a foreign object, since the vessel for some reason gets handled as detached. I know that it can be solved by attaching the vessel-object, that is not what im looking for, since it should be attached when queryed for in the first place.

**IRepository**

```
T FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
```

**EFRepository (Implementing IRepository)**

```
public T FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }
```

**Calling it**

```
    private readonly IRepository<VesselModel> _vesselRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<InspectionModel> _inspectionRepository;

    public Constr(IRepository<VesselModel> vesselRepository, IRepository<InspectionModel> inspectionRepository){
        _vesselRepository = vesselRepository;
        _inspectionRepository = inspectionRepository;
    }

    public void RunConnection(int vesselId){
        var vessel = _vesselRepository.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.OrigId == vesselId);
        var inspection = new Inspection{Vessel = vessel};
        _inspectionRepository.Add(inspection);
        _inspectionRepository.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Are your repositories creating separate contexts?

Comment: This was set up in a console application, and the context was set up as InstancePerLifeTimeScope. That didnt work very well, because the context was recreated. Tried to change it to SingleInstance, problem gone. Will set it up in a webservice project and change it to InstancePerHttpRequest, i guess that'll do it

Comment: You might also want to look at the Unit of Work pattern.